# How to solve the exception on Flutter Camera plugin stopVideoRecording method?

Tags: android, flutter, android-camera

I am getting this error:

```
Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(error, stop failed., null, java.lang.RuntimeException: stop failed.
    at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native Method)
    at io.flutter.plugins.camera.Camera.stopVideoRecording(Camera.java:645)
    at io.flutter.plugins.camera.MethodCallHandlerImpl.onMethodCall(MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:120)
    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:818)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:183)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)        
))
```

Camera plugin version is  `camera: ^0.7.0+2`

**Flutter version :** `Flutter (Channel beta, 1.26.0-17.3.pre, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)`

I am on `Ubuntu 20`.
It was working fine but suddenly stopped working and also no upgrades.
Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Same issue i am facing below android 11 OS.
have you got any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue by setting resolutionPreset of the CameraController to medium and by deleting the video from the cache memory of the device once you are done with it

Use the below code to delete the video from the cache

```
File(filePath).delete();
```

Make Sure to clear the app cache before applying changes

Answer (score 0):

Try and catch this method . It can work

```
try {
    // add your stopVideoRecording method here
} catch (e) {
   
}
```

**Example**:

```
CameraController _controller;
bool _isRecordingMode = false;
bool _isRecording = false;
final _timerKey = GlobalKey<VideoTimerState>();
  
Future<void> stopVideoRecording() async {
    if (!_controller.value.isRecordingVideo) {
      return null;
    }
    _timerKey.currentState.stopTimer();
    setState(() {
      _isRecording = false;
    });

    try {
      await _controller.stopVideoRecording();
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I already have it something like this to catch error: `
                        _controller
                            .stopVideoRecording()
                            .then((value) =>
                                // Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/show_recorded_video',
                                //     arguments: {'video_path': value.path}));
                                setState(() => {videoPath = value.path}))
                            .catchError((onError) => print(onError));
                      },`

Comment: Don't print the error just catch it . Try my example

Comment: nope doesnt help.. `try {
      final value = await _controller.stopVideoRecording();
      setState(() => {videoPath = value.path});
    } catch (e) {}`

Comment: I update my answer with an example . Please try it

Comment: what is that VideoTImeState? system cant find it .